# sysctl: setting key "net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_source_route": Invalid argument While loading kernel modules for kubernetes

Tags: kernel, 22.04, kubernetes

Following the indications found here: https://www.linuxtechi.com/install-kubernetes-on-ubuntu-22-04/ I'm trying to install Kubernetes cluster on Ubuntu 22.04

On Step 2 : Load the kernel module I'm getting an error on worker-1 :

```
root@k8s-eu-1-worker-1:~# sudo tee /etc/modules-load.d/containerd.conf <<EOF
> overlay
> br_netfilter
> EOF
overlay
br_netfilter

root@k8s-eu-1-worker-1:~# sudo tee /etc/sysctl.d/kubernetes.conf <<EOF
> net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 1
> net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 1
> net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
> EOF
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 1
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 1
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

root@k8s-eu-1-worker-1:~# sudo sysctl --system
* Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-console-messages.conf ...
kernel.printk = 4 4 1 7
* Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-ipv6-privacy.conf ...
net.ipv6.conf.all.use_tempaddr = 2
net.ipv6.conf.default.use_tempaddr = 2
* Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-kernel-hardening.conf ...
kernel.kptr_restrict = 1
* Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-magic-sysrq.conf ...
kernel.sysrq = 176
* Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-network-security.conf ...
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 2
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 2
* Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf ...
kernel.yama.ptrace_scope = 1
* Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-zeropage.conf ...
vm.mmap_min_addr = 65536
* Applying /usr/lib/sysctl.d/50-default.conf ...
kernel.core_uses_pid = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 2
net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_source_route = 0
sysctl: setting key "net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_source_route": Invalid argument
net.ipv4.conf.default.promote_secondaries = 1
sysctl: setting key "net.ipv4.conf.all.promote_secondaries": Invalid argument
net.ipv4.ping_group_range = 0 2147483647
net.core.default_qdisc = fq_codel
fs.protected_hardlinks = 1
fs.protected_symlinks = 1
fs.protected_regular = 1
fs.protected_fifos = 1
* Applying /usr/lib/sysctl.d/50-pid-max.conf ...
kernel.pid_max = 4194304
* Applying /usr/lib/sysctl.d/99-protect-links.conf ...
fs.protected_fifos = 1
fs.protected_hardlinks = 1
fs.protected_regular = 2
fs.protected_symlinks = 1
* Applying /etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf ...
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
kernel.panic = 10
* Applying /etc/sysctl.d/kubernetes.conf ...
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
* Applying /etc/sysctl.conf ...
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
kernel.panic = 10
```

What's going on? How to make it work without errors?

Comment: So far as I can tell, these messages are normal and are not related to the changes you made

Comment: @steeldriver Actually I tried few times again and the messages disappeared. So, I guess, I probably made some typing errors...  Thank you for giving me your feedback

Comment: I installed kubernetes on an Ubuntu 22.04 VM and noticed today that it is having issues resolving certain hosts but I didn't think it was related to installing kube. I decided to check sysctl and did `sysctl --system` and got the exact same errors you have, googled it and this post was the top result so i definitely think it is related to kube.

Comment: Thank you @vulpinus

Answer (score 0):

I was using vagrant with "ubuntu/jammy64" **22.04.3 LTS** and I got the same issue

```
 * Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-console-messages.conf ...
kernel.printk = 4 4 1 7
* Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-ipv6-privacy.conf ...
net.ipv6.conf.all.use_tempaddr = 2
net.ipv6.conf.default.use_tempaddr = 2
* Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-kernel-hardening.conf ...
kernel.kptr_restrict = 1
* Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-magic-sysrq.conf ...
kernel.sysrq = 176
* Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-network-security.conf ...
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 2
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 2
* Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf ...
kernel.yama.ptrace_scope = 1
* Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-zeropage.conf ...
vm.mmap_min_addr = 65536
* Applying /usr/lib/sysctl.d/50-default.conf ...
kernel.core_uses_pid = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 2
net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_source_route = 0
sysctl: setting key "net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_source_route": Invalid argument
net.ipv4.conf.default.promote_secondaries = 1
sysctl: setting key "net.ipv4.conf.all.promote_secondaries": Invalid argument
net.ipv4.ping_group_range = 0 2147483647
net.core.default_qdisc = fq_codel
fs.protected_hardlinks = 1
fs.protected_symlinks = 1
fs.protected_regular = 1
fs.protected_fifos = 1
* Applying /usr/lib/sysctl.d/50-pid-max.conf ...
kernel.pid_max = 4194304
* Applying /etc/sysctl.d/99-cloudimg-ipv6.conf ...
net.ipv6.conf.all.use_tempaddr = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.use_tempaddr = 0
* Applying /usr/lib/sysctl.d/99-protect-links.conf ...
fs.protected_fifos = 1
fs.protected_hardlinks = 1
fs.protected_regular = 2
fs.protected_symlinks = 1
* Applying /etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf ...
* Applying /etc/sysctl.d/k8s.conf ...
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 1
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 1
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
* Applying /etc/sysctl.conf ...
```

So, I changed the Ubuntu version to **"ubuntu/bionic64" version "20230124.0.0"** and That solved the issue

```
    sudo sysctl --system
* Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-console-messages.conf ...
kernel.printk = 4 4 1 7
* Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-ipv6-privacy.conf ...
net.ipv6.conf.all.use_tempaddr = 2
net.ipv6.conf.default.use_tempaddr = 2
* Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-kernel-hardening.conf ...
kernel.kptr_restrict = 1
* Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-link-restrictions.conf ...
fs.protected_hardlinks = 1
fs.protected_symlinks = 1
* Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-lxd-inotify.conf ...
fs.inotify.max_user_instances = 1024
* Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-magic-sysrq.conf ...
kernel.sysrq = 176
* Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-network-security.conf ...
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1
* Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf ...
kernel.yama.ptrace_scope = 1
* Applying /etc/sysctl.d/10-zeropage.conf ...
vm.mmap_min_addr = 65536
* Applying /usr/lib/sysctl.d/50-default.conf ...
net.ipv4.conf.all.promote_secondaries = 1
net.core.default_qdisc = fq_codel
* Applying /etc/sysctl.d/99-cloudimg-ipv6.conf ...
net.ipv6.conf.all.use_tempaddr = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.use_tempaddr = 0
* Applying /etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf ...
* Applying /etc/sysctl.d/k8s.conf ...
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 1
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 1
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
* Applying /etc/sysctl.conf ...
```